# How to read in a list of numbers 1-6 and count the repeated numbers java

Tags: java, simulation, dice

So I am trying to read in from a file that has upwards of 10000000 numbers in it that range from 1-6. Essentially the point of this exercise is to simulate a dice being rolled and I need to find the probability of each number being rolled. I wrote code to write random numbers 1-6 to a file which is:

```
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Rolls.txt"));
    System.out.println("Input a number for the amount of rolls");

    long rolls = kb.nextLong();

    for(int i = 0; i< rolls; i++){
        
        if(i % 20 == 0){
            pw.println();
        }
        else{
        pw.print(((int)(Math.random()*6)+1) + ",");
        }
    }


   
    pw.close();
}
```

So using this file I suppose I am supposed to read in an entire line as a string, then split the line at the comma and then change the strings to longs/ints. What I'm struggling with is that I'm supposed to count the number of 1's .... 6's and store that number into another array, and the take each element of that array and find the probability of it getting rolled. The code I have this far for this second part is below. I tried some things but nothing worked and I'm stumped.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Rolls.txt"));
    long[] list = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
   
    while ( in.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(",");
       
       
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to iterate through the items in `numbers`, convert each from a string to an integer (see `Integer.parseInt`), then increment the item at the respective index in `line` (i.e. `line[roll]++`).

Comment: What exact problem are you having? What did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: "I tried something but not working " isn't a working problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you used to generate the rolls didn't do very well. It put an empty new line at the start of the file because i was equal to 0 in the first iteration of the cycle. The second problem was that the number of generated rolls was less that the amount you wanted because on some iterations you wrote a new line only and no number. This is how I modified your code to generate the rolls correctly.

```
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Rolls.txt"));
    System.out.println("Input a number for the amount of rolls");

    long rolls = kb.nextLong();

    for(int i = 1; i<= rolls; i++){

        if(i % 20 == 0){
            pw.println();
        }
        pw.print(((int)(Math.random()*6)+1) + ",");
    }



    pw.close();
}
```

Now here is the continuation of your code for reading and calculating probabilities. As some people have already commented you should use Integer.parseInt(); to get the string values as integers.

```
        public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
                Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Rolls.txt"));
                long[] list = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
                while ( in.hasNextLine()){
                        String line = in.nextLine();
                        String[] numbers = line.split(",");
                        //parse the string to ints
                        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
                                int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
                                list[currentValue-1]++;
                        }
                }
                long totalRollCount=0;
                for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                        totalRollCount+=list[i];
                }
                System.out.println(totalRollCount);
                for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                        System.out.println((i+1)+" "+((double)list[i]/totalRollCount));
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the the things you are taking in are all ints you could probably use them as the keys

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Rolls.txt"));
    long[] list = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int parsed;

    while ( in.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(",");

        for (String number : numbers) {
            parsed = Integer.parseInt(number);
            list[parsed - 1]++;
        }
    }
```

**I have not tested this but it should work

Comment: I get a fat error when I try to run this. I get : Exception in thread "main" . Am i doing anything wrong? or does this not work?

Answer (score 1):

Kamen Vakavchiev and Alexandre Hassan's answer is good,but I want support another method use Java 8 Stream API to make code more simple and readable.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Rolls.txt"));
Map<String, Long> result = reader.lines()
    .flatMap((Function<String, Stream<String>>) s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.summingLong(value -> 1)));
System.out.println(result);
```

A possible output is:

```
{1=166381, 2=166643, 3=167300, 4=166644, 5=166197, 6=166835}
```

Comment: or `Map<String, Long> freq = reader.lines().flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(",")))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> str,Collectors.counting()));`  But I suspect the OP is new to Java and should focus on the basics first.

Comment: @WJS  very agree